# Sets a collection of query parameters for the query being constructed

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to build a query by using array of options, as you see this is my array options:

```
    $sort = $this->getParam('sort', 'creation_date');
    $order = $this->getParam('order', 'desc');   
     $options = [
            'sort' => [$sort => $order],
            'filters' => [
                [
                    'field' => 'state',
                    'operator' => 'LIKE',
                    'bind_name' => 'state1',
                    'value' => 'read',
                    'type' => 'OR'
                ],
                [
                    'field' => 'state',
                    'operator' => 'LIKE',
                    'bind_name' => 'state2',
                    'value' =>  'green'
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

As result i have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mytabel` `mytabel` INNER JOIN state_type t ON t.id_state_type = `mytabel`.id_state_type WHERE (`mytabel`.`state` LIKE :state1) **AND** (`mytabel`.`state` LIKE :state2) ORDER BY `mytabel`.`creation_date` desc

Params
state1  %read%
state2  %green%
```

My question is how i can have OR instead of AND in my query (array options)? because as result i want to have both of them (state1  %read% ,state2  %green%).

Thank you,

Comment: Which lib are you using? Put a little more of your code. How `$options` is used?

Comment: I'm using Doctrine and concerning $options:
I use $options as parameter for generation my tabel $paginator

public function getPaginator(array $options = [])

Comment: Hmmm, I just created [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54328925/1155833) to a slightly newer question. [Doctrine Criteria docs (filter collections)](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) about creating such queries and the [full Criteria docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/collections/latest/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Criteria.html). If you give that a try and then update your question? ;-)