# Best practices with current date in doctrine/php

Tags: php, datetime, doctrine-orm, query-builder

i had to retrieve datas with doctrine based on **current date**, i wanted to know what was the best practices about it. Should i :

- Pass an DateTime object representing current time as parameter of my function so i could test easily my function
- Instantiate an DateTime object in the setParameter() of my QueryBuilder
- Or just use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() of mysql in my query builder

I'm a bit lost with those choices and why should i or not choose an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Doctrine, then the last option should by definition not be used, as Doctrine has functionality for the creation of queries. So either pass the DateTime object as a param, for example to a repository function and/or use instantiate a new DateTime object when you're using the QueryBuilder.

As a param for a function, e.g. in Repository:

```
function getStuff(DateTime $from)
{ 
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->andWhere(
        $criteria::expr()->eq('from', $from)
    );

    return $this->matching($criteria);
}
```

Or if you always want to use "now":

```
function getStuff()
{ 
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->andWhere(
        $criteria::expr()->eq('from', new DateTime('now'))
    );

    return $this->matching($criteria);
}
```

**Why as a param**

You might want to allow the date (and/or time) to be set by the user and as such let it be passed from a Controller and/or Service

**Why 'now'**

You might want to always return something from/until now.

---

Mind, instead of `'now'` you could use another [relative format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) to set a DateTime default, for example:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('last day of'); // Sets date to last day of the current month
```

---

[More on using Doctrine Criteria](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections)

[And the full class docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/collections/latest/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Criteria.html)